# IE6 & IE7 messing up dynamic HTML generated by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

I am wondering my IE6 and IE7 is messing up dynamic HTML generated by JavaScript (use with FancyBox and jQuery).

For example:

```
var html = '<a href="#fancyBoxContent" class="fancybox"></a>';
document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = html;
```

Instead of filling the container with '`<a href="#fancyBoxContent" class="fancybox"></a>`', it becomes '`<a href="http://website.com/#fancyBoxContent" class="fancybox"></a`>'.

Any type of HTML/CSS which is valid, but IE6 and IE7 considers 'odd' gets all messed up. I could create HTML with DOM elements, but while this example is simple, it would mean my more complex code will result in javascript which is many times more complex and long. Also, cross compat becomes a issue as well as not always being able to control the exact synax of the HTML code being generated. Hence why I create dynamic HTML using javascript in this manner, DOM elements and builders break a lot of the valid HTML/CSS I try to generate.

Any ways around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way that I am aware of around this particular issue. It shouldn't cause any problems, though. Behavioral wise, `http://website.com/foo#fancyBoxContent` and `#fancyBoxContent` is the same, given the URL of the current page is `http://website.com/foo`.

Comment: It does, i'm using it with FancyBox + jQuery where the href parameter refers to the ID of the element which will be displayed. Hence #fancyBoxContent = <div id="fancyBoxContent"... http://website.com/foo#fancyBoxContent messing that all up. As explained, i need HTML to be rendered exactly. also, as explained, this is a simple example, and ignoring the issue does not solve the issue.

Comment: That's a bug in FancyBox, then. Perhaps you can use a different attribute, i.e. "data-fancybox-href". IE is only altering the href attribute on `<a>` tags in this manner.

Comment: ok... for the third time, this is a simple example, what happens when you try to write 'style' tags into the page via innerHTML? IE6 writes nothing. Basically, how to stop IE6 from messing up the string set into a element via innerHTML. using differnt attributes don't work either, because they are not considered 'valid' by IE6 and hence stripped out.

Comment: there are many many many examples which do not involve jquery of fancybox, its a wider issue of strings being messed up when set via innerHTML

Comment: I'm pretty sure IE alters the anchor attribute regardless of being inserted with the DOM API, innerHTML or in the HTML itself when the page loads.